# Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule error

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide library to load images in android earlier Glide was loading images easily but now it is showing error though image url are showing in log cat but unable to load in image view.

It is showing below error:

> Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an 
>       annotationProcessor compile dependency on 
>       com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a 
>       @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or 
>       LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

android {
     compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.bookbudiapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {

     implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
     annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}  

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**MyGlideApp**

```
@GlideModule
public class MyGlideApp extends AppGlideModule {}
```

**HomeOfferAdapter.java**

```
     public class HomeOfferAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<HomeOffersModel> banners;

    public HomeOfferAdapter(List<HomeOffersModel> banners,Context context){

                 this.banners = banners;
                 this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return banners.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        assert layoutInflater != null;
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.onboard_frag,container,false);

        ImageView slideImage = view.findViewById(R.id.offerImage);

        HomeOffersModel model = banners.get(position);

      //  RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
      //  options.placeholder(R.drawable.openbook);



            GlideApp.with(context).load(model.getOffers()).placeholder(R.drawable.openbook).into(slideImage);


        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

**Error after rebuilding project:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.ProcessorUtil.findInstanceMethodsReturning(ProcessorUtil.java:474)
at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.RequestOptionsOverrideGenerator.generateInstanceMethodOverridesForRequestOptions(RequestOptionsOverrideGenerator.java:49)
at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.RequestOptionsOverrideGenerator.generateInstanceMethodOverridesForRequestOptions(RequestOptionsOverrideGenerator.java:41)
at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.RequestOptionsGenerator.generate(RequestOptionsGenerator.java:157)
at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.AppModuleProcessor.maybeWriteAppModule(AppModuleProcessor.java:87)
at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.GlideAnnotationProcessor.process(GlideAnnotationProcessor.java:131)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.AggregatingProcessor.process(AggregatingProcessor.java:50)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
... 69 more
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Have you tried it without creating a `requestionOptions` object? Like `Glide.with(context).placeholder(x).load(model.getOffers).into(ImageView)` ?

Comment: Yes I tried but giving error.

Comment: When I am using GlideApp it is showing in red and showing suggestions create a class GlideApp.

Comment: Try changing your Glide dependency to newer. Use this: `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'`. After syncing, clean and rebuild the project. I am not exactly sure right now why it is happening, I am using Glide myself with no issues.

Comment: Yes now it changes to GlideApp but showing another error

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.bookbudiapp, PID: 6396
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null

Comment: It appears that somewhere the object you are using is null. I need to see your code, update the logs in your original post and explain a little bit how you are loading data, meaning where the data is coming from and such. Also, if the error points to a line, please mark it on your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195215/discussion-between-taseer-ahmad-and-digvijay).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation from Glide on GitHub:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google() // You were missing this
}

 dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' //bumped from 4.8.0 to 4.9.0
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

Always make sure to use the latest version. It was being caused due to missing `google()` repository in your project level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

try to rebuild the project and use GlideApp instead of Glide like following code:

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(model.getOffers).apply(options).into(slideImage);
```

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: update your code to  `GlideApp.with(context).load(model.getOffers).apply(new RequestOptions().override(dimenInPx, dimenInPx).placeholder(R.drawable.openbook)).into(slideImage);`

Comment: and you must delete `RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
 options.placeholder(R.drawable.openbook);`

Comment: are you trying to import it by Alt+Enter?

Comment: BUt before that when I try to rebuild project there were an error.

Comment: before add `GlideApp` you shoud rebuild your project. change it to `Glide` and rebuild and after change to `GlideApp` again

Comment: Yes I am trying to rebuild project before changing Glide to GlideApp but it is showing error after rebuilding in console that I have posted in my question.

Comment: Do you add `override `  to RequestOption?   `Glide.with(context).load(model.getOffers).apply(new RequestOptions().override(dimenInPx, dimenInPx).placeholder(R.drawable.openbook)).into(slideImage)` and rebuild and after that change `Glide` to `GlideApp`

Comment: I am simply using

Comment: GlideApp.with(context).load(model.getOffers()).placeholder(R.drawable.openbook).into(slideImage);